# How can i color one sector

Tags: highcharts

i'm using a line chart which represent number of players every 5 minutes on our servers and i would like to show a drop in the player count and to present it with coloring the particular sector between the two points where the drop occurred, i didn't find the option to do it,
for example the line of the player count is colored on blue and when the drop is occured i would like to represent only the drop in red so the rest of the line will stay blue.

is it possible? or even just to highlight the specific sector?

Comment: Whenever this question is asked, I have to ask back:  Why? The fact that the line is now pointed downward should be more than enough information to determine that the number is declining.  The answer below will solve your problem, but I suggest that unless there is a really specific reason to highlight a particular drop, it's a generally bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a direct way of doing it(highcharts do not provide that kind of customisation yet, maybe they will if you can add a ticket in their website for this particular suggestion and if others vote up, they will consider implementing it). But you can get the result by doing a get around like this :

Instead of plotting everything in a single chart, split it into two : 
1. Rise (color 1)
2. Dips (color 2)

See the pic below for more insight :

[image]

Where the values would be  :

```
    A        B             C
1            Rise          Dip
2   2002     0.273966   
3   2003     0.126777   
4   2004     0.584197      0.584197
5   2005                   0.898247
6   2006                   0.560888
7   2007                   0.144713
8   2008                   0.632703
9   2009                   0.604576
10  2010                   0.779904
```

Just split the rise and dips into two different plots and you will get the result you want..

But you need to do some calculations at your end..:)

Comment: I think your terminology is a little confusing.  the answer is the right one, but it's important to clarify that the data needs to be split into 2 *series* - not 2 charts, not 2 plots.